# что за противоречивость языка, в документации написано что инициализаторы(конструкторы) не наследуются, но они наследуются

Tags: swift, наследование

```
class Food {
    var name: String
    init (_ name : String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init("Unnamed")
    }   
}

class RecipeIngredient: Food {
    var quantity: Int   
    init(_ name : String,_ quantity : Int) {
        self.quantity = quantity
        super.init(name)
    }

    override convenience init(_ name : String) {
        self.init(name, 1)
    }
    
}

let oneMysteryItem  = RecipeIngredient()
print(oneMysteryItem.quantity)
```

Comment: Где вы нашли в документации, что они не наследуются? В документации есть только строка `Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses don’t inherit their superclass initializers by default`. Окончание предложения by default в сравнении с другим языком означает, что swift не тащит все конструкторы подряд в наследников. А дальше по документации у вас идет большая глава с пометкой `As mentioned above, subclasses don’t inherit their superclass initializers by default. However, superclass initializers are automatically inherited if certain conditions are met. `

Comment: а можно пример где часть инициализаторов не наследуется @AlexKrass

Comment: К сожалению тут я вам не подскажу, поскольку этот язык не входит в мой список и знаком я с ним весьма поверхностно. При попытке углубиться в тему двойных инициализаторов и как они взаимодействуют друг с другом могу запросто ошибиться.

Answer (score 1):

Если подкласс имеет собственный назначенный инициализатор (в вашем примере это init(_ name : String,_ quantity : Int)), то инициализаторы родительского класса не наследуются. Если подкласс переопределяет все назначенные инициализаторы суперкласса (override convenience init), то он наследует и все его вспомогательные инициализаторы (convenience init).

Именно поэтому у вас срабатывает init() из Food:

```
let oneMysteryItem  = RecipeIngredient()
print(oneMysteryItem.quantity) // 1
print(oneMysteryItem.name) // Unnamed
```

Но если вы уберете из RecipeIngredient

```
override convenience init(_ name : String) {
    self.init(name, 1)
}
```

То init() из Food уже не наследуется и строка let oneMysteryItem  = RecipeIngredient() выдаст ошибку.